# Application that display on another monitor/TV

Tags: c#, network-programming, screen, television

I have an c# desktop Application that want to display the videos with sounds that was streaming via axwindowsmediaplayer and after then the timer start and display message if necessary on tv, what I did I made "axwindowsmediaplayer and labels that calculate the timer and message on (panel2) and all works fine " but **I want to display panel 2 on tv screen** with audio if another technology please advise me  .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAq3e.jpg)

```
Screen pscr = Screen.FromControl(panel2);
            Screen scr = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Primary) ??pscr ;
            panel2.Left = scr.Bounds.Width;
            panel2.Top = scr.Bounds.Height;
            panel2.Location = scr.Bounds.Location;
            Point p = new Point(scr.Bounds.Location.X, scr.Bounds.Location.Y);
            panel2.Location = p;
            panel2.Show();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Is it that, you want another way to do what you have already done?

Comment: I want to ask if there is away to display panel2 on tv ?  or if there is another way that is more professional ?